# Script to find all items that do not inherit permissions for Sharepoint 2007

Tags: powershell, 2007, item-level-permissions

I was wondering if there is a script or two that can be run to find out all items that have specific unique permissions and also list WHO has access to the items?

I need to migrate over 3 million documents out of SP2007, but a lot of the documents may have unique, uninherited permissions and I cannot see an automated way of capturing this information.

Sorry I am new to all of this

Thanks for any advice given

Comment: Sharepoint 2007 didn' had PowerSHell support. you were using stsadm for administartion. You can use server object model with SP 2007 (inside powershell) http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/05/how-to-use-powershell-with-sharepoint-2007.html

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-ItemsWithUniquePermissions(){
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$folderPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$rootSiteUrl
)

$folder=$folderPath
$date=Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"

$fileName="ItemsWithUniquePermissions$date.csv"


if(!(Test-Path $folder)){
    New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType directory
}

if(!(Test-Path $errorLog)){
    New-Item -Path $errorLog -ItemType file
}


[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($rootSiteUrl)



$webs=$rootSite.AllWebs

foreach($web in $webs){
    $lists=$web.lists | ?{$_.hidden -eq $false}
    foreach($list in $lists){
        $items=$list.items
        foreach($item in $items){
            if ($item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) {
                $itemData= new-object psobject
                $itemData |Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Web -Value "$($web.url)"
                $itemData |Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name List -Value $($list.title)
                $itemData |Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Item -Value $($item.id)

                $itemData |Export-Csv -Path "$folder\$filename" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Get-ItemsWithUniquePermissions -folderPath c:\temp -rootSiteUrl http://dev